# Ajax-Jquery-Checkbox-PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am little confused about how to go with the following proceedings

```
<input id="" type="checkbox" name="" onClick="" />
    <td>
    <h4>PDF Document</h4>
    <p>
    Already have your own menu or flyer? Include it in your App
    </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cost">$99.99 per document
    </td>
```

Now what i want is the word "PDF Document" with its cost $99.99,display on a different dv panel when checkbox is gets checked,no refresh just post to different div

Pls give me the relevant example.How to start

Comment: What is the id attribute of the target <div> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id to the `td` having the cost and also an id to the `checkbox`, then you can get the desired result as follows:

Consider your HTML part to be :

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" name="" />
   <table>
    <tr>
       <td>   
           <h4>PDF Document</h4>
           <p>Already have your own menu or flyer? Include it in your App</p>
        </td>
       <td class="cost" id="tdId">$99.99 per document</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="result">
asdasdasd
</div>​
```

The script required to do the job should be:

```
$('#1').click(function(){
if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked')
    $('#result').text("PDF Document" + $('#tdId').text());
else
    $('#result').text("");
```

});
​

http://jsfiddle.net/n57Te/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n57Te/

Comment: @CreativeSolution: http://jsfiddle.net/hWCCP/

Comment: first of all remove 'tdToDiv()' from the onClick and also do away with the <script> tags from the script part, that isn't required in jsfiddle's script part.

Comment: @raynjamin pls ammend some last tweak that if checkbox gets unchecked it will back to its normal position,the default value

Comment: @CreativeSolution: I will leave that up to you. I think you have sufficient information to figure this out on your own. Creatively.

Comment: @CreativeSolution : you had also not selected the 'jquery' lib on the left, it was left to 'mootools', that was also the reason of it not working!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n57Te/5/

Comment: Here you go, I have edited it to have it back to normal once unchecked: http://jsfiddle.net/n57Te/6/

Comment: To find that it is currently the checkbox has been ticked or not, following check is enough `($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked'`

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
<input id="" type="checkbox" name="" onClick="tdToDiv()" />
    <td>
    <h4>PDF Document</h4>
    <p>
    Already have your own menu or flyer? Include it in your App
    </p>
    </td>
    <td class="cost" id="tdId">$99.99 per document
    </td>
<div id="result"></div>
```

js:

```
function tdToDiv() {
document.getElelmentById('result').innerHTML=document.getElementById('tdId').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Not working,can pls do it in a fiddle

Comment: What error you get? Have you look on your console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ppcFJ/

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you use jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').bind('click', function(){
        if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
            $('#results').html($('h4').text() + ': ' + $('.cost').text());
        }else{
            $('#results').html('');
        }
    });
});
```

I would recommend to use ID attribute for your elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H7eSA/ is this correct ??

Comment: These selectors will fail to do what you want on any given website. This will also overwrite the original text instead of saving it.

Comment: @CreativeSolution, Please keep in mind that `td` should be always wrapped with `table tr`. If you test it in jsfiddle.net, you don't need ` $(document).ready()`.

Comment: @CreativeSolution, see http://jsfiddle.net/H7eSA/1/